# Is Descent: Champions set in Oriath?

Tags: path-of-exile

I have tried racing in Path of Exile after a year-long break and was stunned to see Descent: Champions. Before, [Descent](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Descent) had locations such as [the Heart of Phrecia](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/The_Heart_of_Phrecia), so it was likely set in Wraeclast. Now, [Descent: Champions](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Descent:_Champions) has Gravicius welcoming contenders and a lot of NPCs (Nessa to Oak to Fairgraves to Hargan) standing in the cheering mob of people at the back of the starting area. Seems like Descent: Champions is set in Oriath, but do we have any confirmation on that from Grinding Gear?

This strikes me as strange: why would you have a hall full of monsters to feed on unlucky contenders in the middle of your capital city? Nuke it from orbit / seal it if you can't. Instead, they are letting adventurers in.

Should I, out-of-universe, think that Descent: Champions is just a race and is not really related to the main game storyline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [original announcement](https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/636802):

> The (non-canon) plot of Descent: Champions is that nobles have created a dungeon full of dangerous monsters for contestants to fight through. Champions from all over the land have come to compete for glory.

That would seem to indicate that **yes**, it does take place in Oriath, as there are certainly no nobles in Wraeclast.